# Why won't my deploy user use my ssh key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, capistrano3

I am trying to fix an ssh key error to work for a deploy user with my RoR Capistrano 3.3.5 project.  I have an ubuntu 14.04 server which has my public ssh key authorized.

If I type `ssh root@server-address.com` my ssh key works, and I am immediately logged into my server.

If I type `ssh deploy@server-address.com` I am prompted for a password.

I need the deploy user to use the same key and authenticate without password.  What is wrong?  How do I go about making this happen?

I appreciate any help you can provide, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add your public key to the deploy user's authorized_keys file which is located at `/home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know there was another .ssh/ folder inside deploy's folder.  Makes complete sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@machine "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

this command would work for a new sever setup too.